# Failure on simple remote kernel configuration

Tags: remote-access, kernel-startup

I have a remote machine in which I can run MathKernel and I want to use it to exploit its cpus on my front-end.

Please note that this machine will run MathKernel using an interactive LSF queue, if that matters.

On this machine, called MyRemote for the example, I can open a MathKernel by just giving one command in the command line

`MyRemote~>./mymath.sh`

I have passwordless access to MyRemote machine via ssh so I set up a remote kernel with the basic options:

Kernel Program: `/home/users/usernameonremote/mymath.sh`

Remote user: `usernameonremote`

Remote host: `MyRemote`

Kernel does not start and the messages pane gives

`The child process 52466 reports: 2015-10-28 17:09:35.838 java[52466:2899691] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore`

`The child process 52466 reports: <<Waiting for dispatch ...>>`

`The child process 52466 reports: <<Starting on LSFqueueName>>`

`The child process 52466 reports:`

`The child process 52466 reports:`

`The kernel MyKernel failed to connect to the front end. (Error = MLECONNECT). You should try running the kernel connection outside the front end.`

Untill the `<<Starting on LSFqueueNAME>>` the reports from the child looks ok, but for the SCDynamicStore error.

First of all does that error mean anything? seems to be a Java related error.

Other than that do you see anything wrong with my configuration? or are you aware of having the Kernel on this interactive LSF queue being a problem?